# What is this key:value pair in this ajax function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can someone help me understand what this key value pair in the $.ajax call does `data:{employee_id:employee_id},`? I have been searching the web and I have seen people use this data parameter in many different ways. I have seen people place a function there, I have seen people put a few key value pairs like `name=john&age=36` and finally what I am specifically asking about `data:{employee_id:employee_id},`. What is the colon for and why is it the same on each side?

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           $('#insert').val("Insert");  
           $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"fetch.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#name').val(data.name);  
                     $('#address').val(data.address);  
                     $('#gender').val(data.gender);  
                     $('#designation').val(data.designation);  
                     $('#age').val(data.age);  
                     $('#employee_id').val(data.id);  
                     $('#insert').val("Update");  
                     $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');  
                }  
           });  
      });
```

Comment: It's an object. `{key:value}`... It's setting the object's `employee_id` property to the `var employee_id` defined above it, and it's the same on both sides because the variable was named the same thing as the key.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
data:{employee_id:employee_id},
```

Passes an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to the `data` setting of your `.ajax()` request. The colon separates the key from the value in an object.

`{employee_id:employee_id}` is an object with a key of `employee_id` and a value of `employee_id`, however the value is actually `$(this).attr("id")` because it's set a few lines above in:

```
var employee_id = $(this).attr("id")
```

So the author could have just as easily written:

```
data:{employee_id:$(this).attr("id")},
```

Ostensibly the author is sending a POST request to a script, fetch.php, and is expecting the `employee_id`, the value of which comes from the ID of an element that was clicked on.

Comment: Thank you. So fetch.php is waiting for a $_POST variable "employee_id" to query the database. Why couldn't I just pass "employee_id" instead of "{employee_id:employee_id}" as the data parameter, why does it need to be as on object? I don't recall where I created an employee_id object.

Comment: The object vs string argument is valid and it depends on what kind of information you're expecting to receive. If the script is just waiting for one value, a string makes sense, but it you're passing multiple values an object probably makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

With an Ajax request you can send the data, which the destination url will receive and can do some manipulations. We can send the data in the form of an **Object**, a **String** or an **Array**

The key value pair that you are referring to is an **Object**. Referring to your line:

```
data:{employee_id:employee_id}
```

It passes an object to the `data` field of your .ajax() request. When received at the other end, you can use this key to retrieve the value.